# I cannot finish activities with "finish()"... :(

Tags: android, android-studio, activity-finish

I'm a beginner in android.

And I'm making an application about health care.

What I want to ask is how to finish an activity in the beneath case.
The problem is the activity is not finished when I push the 'Back button' and 'ImageButton29'. To be specific, the countdowntimer still operates after I push those buttons... So, even if I go to next or previous pages(activity), after the countdown, the 'pushtaba2' activity is implemented. Please answer me.

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pushtaba1.*
import android.content.Intent as Intent

class pushtaba1 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finish()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pushtaba1)

        val intent = Intent(this, pushtaba2::class.java)

        val value = object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                mTextField3.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }

        }.start()

        imageButton29.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the fun `onDestroy()` in `AppCompatActivity`. This will be called whenever the Activity gets destroyed.

```
class pushtaba1 : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // TODO - stop your timer here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `finishAffinity()` or override `onDestroy()` and destroy the activity

Answer (score 0):

This is just to add to Roshana's Answers.

`onDestroy()` is only called when you call `finish()` on your activity or ***the System is temporary destroying the activity***.

With this in mind you need to declare the timer as `lateinit` property so that it can be used inside `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`.

```
class pushtaba1 : AppCompatActivity() {
    
//declare timer here
    private lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { ...}
```

I would also ***create a separate method to start the intent*** since you may need to the intent on a button click or when the timer elapses. Inside the method I call `finish()` to make sure onDestroy() is called to cancel the timer

```
private fun moveToNextActivity(){

        val intent = Intent(this@pushtaba1, pushtaba2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        //make sure you call finish to force onDestroy() to be called
        finish()
    }
```

The next thing is to ***intilize and start the timer*** inside the `onCreate()` method.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

timer = object:CountDownTimer(10000,1000){
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                //consider using String resources for this
                  mTextField3.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                moveToNextActivity()
            }
        
        }

//start the timer
        timer.start()
```

Lastly ***override the onDestroy() and stop the timer*** inside the onDestroy() method

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        //stopping the timer
        timer.cancel()
        
    }
```